# Creating a table from excel VBA to write into word document throws error 'Runtime Error 6028' when making multiple tables

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm fairly new to VBA, but essentially what I am trying to do is create a script that takes in a data set from a csv and parses out missing fields, it then exports them with its given title into a word document. This itself works fine and dandy. The problem comes when I try to format this data into a table within word. For example, here is what my data set looks like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAFTc.png)

and here is what is looks like when I run the script and is already written into a word file [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm9j9.png)

When the script is iterated through each row. I want to create a new table for every row entry, but after the first one executes and the first table is created, the program crashes and I receive this error message: "Run-time error '6028': Application-defined or object-defined error". As far as I have been able to tell this has to do with the range not getting deleted properly. Anyway, here is my code:

```
Sub FunctionFnWriteToWordDoc()
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Dim objSelection
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim objTable
    Dim strVal As String
    
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objRange = objDoc.Range
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
    j = 2
    
    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(j, 1).Value)
        Dim rowCount As Integer
        Dim colCount As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        
        rowCount = 0
        colCount = 1
        
        For i = 1 To 19
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(2, i).Value) Then
                rowCount = rowCount + 2
            End If
        Next i
        objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, rowCount, colCount
        Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
        objTable.Borders.Enable = True
        
        k = 1
        For i = 1 To 19
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(2, i).Value) Then
                strVal = Cells(1, i)
                objTable.Cell(k, 1).Range.Text = strVal
                strVal = Cells(j, i)
                objTable.Cell(k + 1, 1).Range.Text = strVal
                k = k + 2
            End If
        Next i
        objSelection.TypeParagraph
        objSelection.TypeParagraph
        j = j + 1
     Wend
End Sub
```

any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub FunctionFnWriteToWordDoc()
    Dim objWord, objDoc, objTable, objRange
    Dim strVal As String, ws As Worksheet, rw As Range, c As Range
    Dim rowCount As Long, colCount As Long, k As Long
    
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    objWord.Visible = True
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    colCount = 2
    
    Set rw = ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 19) 'first row of data
    
    Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0
        
        rowCount = Application.CountA(rw)
        
        Set objRange = objDoc.Content
        objRange.Collapse Direction:=0  'wdCollapseEnd
        objRange.InsertAfter vbCrLf
        objRange.Collapse Direction:=0
        
        'Tables.Add returns a Table object, so you can use that...
        Set objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(objRange, rowCount, colCount)
        objTable.Columns(1).Width = objWord.InchesToPoints(2)
        objTable.Borders.Enable = True
        
        k = 1
        For Each c In rw.Cells
            strVal = c.Value
            If Len(strVal) > 0 Then
                objTable.Cell(k, 1).Range.Text = ws.Cells(1, c.Column).Value
                objTable.Cell(k, 2).Range.Text = strVal
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next c
        
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'Next row
    Loop
End Sub
```